# EF4.1 Using T4 in another C# project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, t4

I have been learning MVVM/EF4 (for C#) recently and have followed Julie Lerman's videos.  In her videos she shows how to create a EDMX in one project and then use it in another project by adding the first as a reference to the second.

I have now come across EF4.1 and would like to know if it is possible to create the EDMX and T4 items (*.tt files) in one project and then use them in another project.  I created the EDMX file and used the 'Add Code Generation Item' option to create the *.tt files in the first project.

Can anyone tell me how this is done or point me to some tutorials?

TIA

Comment: I would not do that. Create domain models and use mappings (automapper) between the entity models and the domain models. Else you'll get a maintenance mess in the future. Any changes to the entity model would affect your entire application.

Comment: @jgauffin Usually I do this and I find it very useful. I can have my .edmx in one project and my domain model (the generated classes) in another, where I add partial classes that contain some more logic. In that way, I can pass around those domain model classes without needing to make reference to the EF.
However, when interacting with the interface layer, I map them to view-models (with the help of Automapper) to keep a nice separation. I bring my domain models to the interface only in a few cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple. You can move your .tt to another project and it will work almost out of the box.
However there are 2 things you should know:

1. Change the reference to the .edmx file inside the T4 template (you must provide the correct file path).
2. Your changes to the model will not be reflected automatically in files generated by the template. You must right-click the template and select "Run Custom Tool" to update the files.

Have you already tried that? Are you having any issues? Report them here and I will try to help.

Comment: Can you explain how I would move the .tt files to my second project?  I have tried cut/paste and also adding existing items.  Cutting/pasting doesn't seem to work and when I try to add an existing item I cannot find any .tt files (I do see the .cs files for all of the individual tables though).

Comment: Inside the Visual Studio, in the Solution Explorer window, I just cut/paste my .tt from the original project to the destination.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, I had the two projects in separate solutions and it wouldn't cut/paste.  Once I opened the two projects in the same solution it worked.

Comment: For your point 1 what do I change the reference to?  In my .tt file I see 'string inputFile = @"MyDataModel.edmx";'  Is this what I would change and to what?  I assume I am changing something to reference the EDMX that I added to my references but not how to do this.

Comment: @BrianKE Yes, that is the string you need to change. You need to insert the relative file path to access your .edmx. For instance, if you have two projects ProjEdmx and ProjTemplate, each one has it's own folder, so in the template (inside the ProjTemplate project) you need to set the path to "..\ProjEdmx\Model.edmx".

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I have one new issue when I try to execute a query.  The message is 'EntityType 'T_Perceptionist' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.'  I believe I am getting this because the table name is T_Perceptionist but the Key column is named PerceptionistID (no 'T_').  I have tried to specify a [Key] attribute but the get a different error about KeyAttribute not defined (and I did include Annotation in the usings).  Do I have to specify this [Key] back in the first project before importing to my second project or is there some other fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem you're having. Maybe you should post it as another question, as it probably is out o scope of your original question. Even though, all the changes to the model need to be done on your first project (on the .edmx designer), but you won't need to import anything anymore, just go to the .tt file, right-click and "Run Custom Tool" to update the classes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best route would be to use the EDMX and Code-First generation item to pull in an existing database and jump-start the Code-first project (rather than manually typing the classes in. After you've generated them (there should be an option to create each class in its own file), delete the t4 and the edmx and move forward by building the code-first model directly.

Comment: If you already have a database, the best option would be to do a Database First approach.

Comment: This project is using an existing database so I have to go with the Database First approach.

Comment: Yes use db first to generate the initial model and then go code-first from there.